# What is function signature if parameters are split by comma rather than colon when invoked?

Tags: objective-c

Read a function call like this in Apple's tutorial for OC. a bit confused about how function stringWithFormat is defined or its signature...

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The magic number is %i", magicNumber];
```

A relative question is about NSLog as

```
NSLog(@"%i is a number", someScalarVarNumber);
```

Should a function call be like

```
[Obj FuncName:param FuncName1:param1 FuncName2:param2];
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_parameter_lists — http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html

Comment: `stringWithFormat` is an Objective-C method. `NSLog` is a C function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> [I am] a bit confused about how function `stringWithFormat` is defined or its signature.

If you <kbd>command</kbd>-click on `stringWithFormat` in your code, it will take you directly to its declaration (and you can hit the "back" button to return to your code). Anyway, `stringWithFormat` is defined as follows:

```
+ (instancetype)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

Those ellipses (`...`) indicate that it is a "[variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)", that it takes a variable length list of parameters separated by commas. This is a C programming pattern which is also incorporated into Objective-C.

In case you're wondering, that `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` is a hint to the compiler that the first parameter (`1`) is a `printf`-style format string (or more accurately, slightly richer rendition that `NSString` uses), and that the parameters starting at the second parameter (`2`) should match up with what appears in the format string. That lets the compiler check your list of parameters to see if it matches the format string.

The fact that they felt compelled to add this special logic for `printf`-style parameters is actually a clue to the deeper problem of variadic parameters: With the exception of `printf`-style case, it's hard to ensure that the parameters passed to the function match what the function was expecting.

As a result, you will generally only see variadic method declarations where the number of parameters being passed to a method is variable and that it has a `printf`-style format string. (Technically, you can use it in any situation with variable number of parameters, but in those situations there are generally better approaches, e.g. pass an array. In fact, if you look at Apple's newer Cocoa API, where they need variable number of parameters, they generally pass an array rather than using the variadic patterns that you'll see in some of the older API.)

So, you're right, we generally invoke a method like so:

```
[objectName funcName:firstValue secondParameterName:secondValue thirdParameterName:thirdValue];
```

But, in special cases, you can employ [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).